# how to bind off-event operation on dynamically called element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Main page:

```
$(".aclass").css("background","green");
//How to bind this on a dynamically called element
// like
$(".placeholder").load("page.php");
```

The page.php contains:

```
<div class="aclass">Some text</div>
```

If I call that load function, the css doesn't work but works on the same page if applied

Answer (score 1):

use callback function of load which is execcuted after the load completes.

```
 $(".placeholder").load("page.php",function(){
    $(".aclass").css("background","green");
 });
```